# Django: logging template errors

Tags: django, logging, django-templates, django-logging

When I make an error in a django template `{{placeholder}}`, I get no error, just blank space in the output where I was expecting content. Is there a way to see something in my logs when this occurs, preferably using `logging.warning` or `logging.error`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing Django provides for handling unknown context variables in [`TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#invalid-template-variables). You're going to have to do some deeper hacking of the template engine if you want better than that.

Comment: Ignacio, with the new versions of Django, is that still the only way to go? Thanks

Comment: `django.template` logger was intoduced in Django 1.9 https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/logging/#django-template

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is. Just add in your development `settings.py`:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.template': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG'),
        },
    },
}
```

As [roboslone stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114887/django-logging-template-errors#comment64355022_2115042), Django 1.9 did introduce it. The snippet is very similar to the second of [Configuring logging examples in Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/logging/#examples).

Answer (score 0):

In Django >= 1.8, `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID` has been deprecated in favor of [`string_if_invalid`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#invalid-template-variables) in `settings.TEMPLATES`.

If you want to do a little more than depend on `DEBUG` messages from the `django.template` logger, you can fool the following code in `django.template.base.FilterExpression.render()`:

```
if '%s' in string_if_invalid:
    return string_if_invalid % self.var
```

With a class like the following:

```
class InvalidString(object):
    def __mod__(self, other):
        log.error('Missing template variable: "%s"', other)
        # ... do other interesting things ... 
        return u''

    def __contains__(self, item):
        return item == '%s'
```

And set `string_if_invalid` in `settings.TEMPLATES`:

```
TEMPLATES = [{
    'OPTIONS': {'string_if_invalid': InvalidString()}
    # ...
}]
```